# $X_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} X$ almost surely implies $\mathbb{E}[|X|] \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[| X_n |]$

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

*Not a homework question but an exercise from an past exam.*

> Let $X, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be real-valued random variables on a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.
>   Show that $X_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} X$ almost surely implies $\mathbb{E}[|X|] \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[| X_n |]$.

I suspect I have to invoke the [Lemma of Fatou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma), which gives
$$
\mathbb{E}[\liminf_{n \to \infty} | X_n |]
\le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_n|]
$$
but I don't know how to related the LHS of this inequality with LHS of the inequality I should prove.

I know that the almost sure convergence means that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} X) = 1,
$$
so there exists a null set $\mathcal{N}$ such that $X_n$ converges to $X$ pointwise everywhere outside of $\mathcal{N}$.

Any help **(preferably only in the form of hints)** is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suppose $X_n$ surely converges to $X$.  Can you relate the LHS now? [In other words, make life easier by (temporarily) changing "almost surely" to "surely".]

Comment: @ Well then also $| X_n | \to | X |$ or $Y_n \to | X |$ with your notation.

Comment: So then in that case we are done, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think about this in 2 steps:

1) Consider the special case when the assumption $X_n\rightarrow X$ **almost surely** is strengthened to **surely**.  In that case we can apply Fatou directly and we are done.

2) What if you modify the random variables $X, X_n$ as follows: Define the event
$$A =\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)\}$$

Note that $P[A]=1$.  Then define new random variables $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{X}_n$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ by
\begin{align}
\tilde{X}(\omega) &=  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
X(\omega) &\mbox{ if $\omega \in A$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.\\
\tilde{X}_n(\omega) &=  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
X_n(\omega) &\mbox{ if $\omega \in A$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
Now $\tilde{X}_n\rightarrow \tilde{X}$ surely.  On the other hand, we have changed the random variables only on a set of measure 0, so the expectations are unchanged.

Comment: You can think of $\tilde{X}(\omega) = X(\omega)1_{\{\omega \in A\}}$ as a product of two measurable functions, if there is doubt that it is itself measurable.

Comment: But isn't the reasoning that because of the convergence almost everywhere the lim and the liminf agree almost everywhere and since the expection (integral) "ignore null sets" much simpler? Or is it incorrect?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik True (+1).  Indeed your argument in the above comment means $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} |X_n|=|X|$ almost surely so $E[\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} |X_n|] = E[|X|]$. I just wanted to reduce it to a case when you can directly use the "surely" result from step 1.  This modification of random variables can often be used to change statements about "almost surely" to statements about "surely" which may be conceptually easier to think about.